# Android ROOM LIVEDATA not emitting the results

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

Hi i have a list of items that i retrieve from a data source and then i apply a map on the observable to store the data into ROOM.

It manages to add it to the table but when i try to retrieve a LiveData of it, It doesnt seem to notify my observer of the results.

There is definetly data in the table and my query works as i changed the return time from LiveData to simple a List and that worked perfectly fine

Here is my data class

```
@Entity
data class Item(
        @PrimaryKey
        val id:String,
        val title: String,
        val description: String,
        val imgUrl: String,
        val  usageRules : List<String>,

)
```

Here is my DAO that exposes a func that add all the list of Items

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun saveAllItems(itemList: MutableList<Item>)

       @Query("SELECT * FROM items")
    fun getAllItems(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>>

}
```

My DB class

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Item::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(UsageRulesTypeConverter::class)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getProductDao(): MyDao
}
```

Below is how i insert data into the database:

```
@Inject
lateInt val database : MyDatabase

   override fun getAllItems(): Single<LiveData<MutableList<Item>>> {
     //retrieve new data using rertrofit
        networkController.getItems().map { responseItems ->
            saveAllItems(responseItems )
            getItems()
}

@Transaction
 fun saveAllItems(allItems: ItemsDataSource) {
    database.getProductDao().saveAllItems(allItems.loadedItems)
    database.getProductDao().saveAllItems(allItems.savedItems)
    database.getProductDao().saveAllItems(allItems.expiredItems)
    database.getProductDao().saveAllItems(allItems.unloadedItems)
}

fun getItems() : LiveData<MutableList<Item>>{

    return database.getProductDao().getAllItems()
}
```

My data source retrieved 4 lists of Items that i then save all of them in one entity/table but LiveData doesnt notify my UI about it?

ViewModel:

```
override fun getUnloadedOffers(): LiveData<MutableList<ProductOffer>> {
        if (!this::itemsLiveData.isInitialized) {
            itemsLiveData= MutableLiveData()
//get data from network or database
            itemDelegator.getItems()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({ items->
                        itemsLiveData= items

                    })
        }

        return itemsLiveData
    }
```

UI

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

     viewModel.getItems().observe(this, Observer {
                items->
                items?.let {
                    adapter = SomeAdapter(items)
                    itemsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your function `getUnloadedOffers()` return empty mutableList? I'm not sure if passing `items` to `itemsLiveData` is going to work, since observing LiveData is running on bg thread (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Yes this was the issue. I had to first grab the live data itself from the sql room query and pass it along my delegator back to the view model

Comment: That's exactly the case, usually you should select LiveData from Room, pass it to ViewModel and subscribe to it in your Activity/Fragment or wherever you need 

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `vararg` instead of `List` when saving collection of data.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun saveAllItems(vararg itemList: Item)
```

And then you can call this method using `*` (also known as `Spread Operator`) on your list like this

```
saveAllItems(*responseItems.toTypedArray())
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the List, but on the official Room tutorial they use varargs, so that should work. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Comment: Room accept an Array of objects not a list for @Insert, Spread Operator worked well for me.

Comment: Diddnt seem to work. The strange thing is room doesn't spit out any insert error so it's hard to debug

Comment: Ok it does actually insert the data but i get another issue. That is, the LiveData doesnt seem to get updated and emit the query from the database.i will update my question